# How can I get Windows to recognize my installed programs on other drives?

Tags: installation, reinstall, search-indexing

I had to reinstall Windows on a new drive, and, of course the new installation does not recognize any of the installed programs that the previous installation had.

- All programs are installed on non-system drives
- I still have access to the previous Windows drive (but cannot run Windows on it)
- For the sake of this question, reinstalling every program is not an option
- I have ***a lot*** of installed programs, many of which have customized settings (such as IDEs etc.)

I want the new installation of Windows to recognize the installations, or at least index them, so I can use the start menu to search for them (and that they appear as programs and not files).

I know that I can run applications from their installation directories and that some of them will work because not all require registry keys etc., but this question is more about how can I make them work as conveniently as possible through the new installation rather than "is it possible to run them".

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Uninstall the programs and then re-install on the new drive. That will work permanently.

Comment: @John thanks for your help, but as I said in the question, reinstalling is something I will do anyway if there are no solutions to this question, so for the sake of this question - reinstalling is not an option.

Answer (score 2):

The install-directories of the programs are the least of an installation - it is doubtful that what you try to do is possible *at all*, as installing a program - no matter to which disk - modifies a lot of things in Windows that are now lost with your reinstall:

- DLLs and similar stuff gets dropped into various Windows system directories
- registry data gets created or modified

There might be more, but manually 'fixing' those two already is a major effort - there is typically no documentation about which files get dropped where, and which registry entries get written (many programs 'hide' their licensing info in obscure registry keys). Even if you had all this info, it will take hours to redo them all (basically, that is what an 'install' does - writing / modifying all this stuff).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Seeing as I have the original Windows drive, is there a way I could restore the registry data and DLLs somehow? I am not very concerned about recovering all the installed programs in working order, but rather just a way in which I can greatly lessen the burden of having to reinstall all of them again?

Answer (score 1):

Windows has never allowed a user to just "move" an installation to another drive and that has (over 95% of the time) always been true.

So you will have to bite the bullet and reinstall programs. It will, in the end, be the fastest, most reliable and most permanent way.